# .NET String.Format with variable string and number of arguments

Tags: .net, string, format

I want to create a method that accepts a string MyString and a List of strings MyList.

MyString contains placeholders like {0}, {1} and so on... but I don't know in advance how many. Example: "I want to put something here: {0} and something there: {1}"

MyList contains the strings that must be substituted in MyString, in their correct place: the first string, with index 0, must be put in the placeholder {0}.

I would like to achieve this with String.Format but I can't understand how to pass MyString as a list of arguments.

Is this possible in VB.NET?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your list to an array, then you're calling [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string result = string.Format(formatString, list.ToArray());
```

For example:

```
string formatString = "I want to put something here: {0} and something there: {1}";
var list = new List<string> { "foo", "bah" };
string result = string.Format(formatString, list.ToArray());
// Result:  I want to put something here: foo and something there: bah
```

If you pass your list the [wrong overload of `String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be(v=vs.110).aspx) is used.

---

Sorry for C#, here VB.NET:

```
Dim result = String.Format(formatString, list.ToArray())
```

Comment: WOW! this was so damn simple but I really didn't even look for an overload! Thankx!